# iOSアプリのメモリ使用量について

Tags: ios, メモリ管理

SwiftでiOSアプリを開発中なのですが、そのアプリのメモリ使用量が気になっています。
開発中のアプリはmap、カメラを使い、ページ数もそれなりに多いものになっており、Simulator上で走らせていると200MB以上のメモリを消費しているのですが、iOSアプリの何か指標になるメモリ使用量などはありますでしょうか。また一般的なメモリ使用量の解決策としてARCによるものがあるかと思いますが、それ以外でTipsなどがありましたら、あわせてご教示いただけますと幸いです。宜しくお願いします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

数値の目安はないと思いますが、メモリが逼迫してくるといくつかの通知がなされます。

最近（たしかiOS6以降）ではアプリのメモリが不足してくると

- UIViewControllerの`didReceiveMemoryWarning`が呼ばれる
- AppDelegateの`applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning`が呼ばれる
- `UIApplicationDidReceiveMemoryWarningNotification`通知が飛ぶ

などの兆候が現れます。その場合に不要なビューの開放やキャッシュなどたくさんメモリを使用していて、あとで再構築できるものを開放する処理を記述していれば問題ないと思います。

参考：

- https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/MemoryUsage.pdf
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32389028/how-to-implement-didreceivememorywarning-in-swift